# Use fiddler/postman for Azure Table Storage REST API

Tags: azure, azure-storage, postman, azure-table-storage

How do we use fiddler for Azure Table Storage REST API. 
For e.g., https://.table.core.windows.net/.
I wanted to see response in JSON/XML using fiddler/postman.

Note : I can use fiddler with blob storage but not with table storage.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found an answer. You have to make request using SAS token. 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcpa9.png)